# SharePoint 2013 list, how to add an "item deletion" button?

Tags: list

can anybody help me on how to add a button or an icon to a SharePoint 2013 list, so that, when one or more items in the list are selected and click on the "deletion" button, the selected items will be getting deleted. I think this can only be achieved by adding a JavaScript code, but i have no idea how. Your help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option A - The SP2013/16 way

Use the [WYSIWYG Cisar Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo) to write CSR-Client Side Rendering javascript to:

- add a button
- grab the ID
- delete the Item with JSOM or REST code

#### Option B - using (unsupported) HTML/JS in a Calculated Column

- Read and understand http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How
- Follow the steps: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/ActionDelete
  [image]

Comment: Hello Danny, thanks for your excellent help .... but it looks to me that there are two problems relating to the solution(Option B): a. after having clicked on the "delete" button, the whole item is getting red but will not disappear until the page is reloaded ... is there a way to remove the item immediately? b. it looks like that the "deleted" item is actually hidden in the current view, but if you export the list to an Excel, it is still in the list, right? can we do a real "deletion"? thanks again